# Deque of user-defined structures

Tags: c++, struct, structure, deque

I've got a user-defined structure `struct theName` and I want to make a deque of these structures (`deque<theName> theVar`). However when I try to compile I get this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
Logger.h:31: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘deque’ with no type
Logger.h:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
```

Why can't I do it this way?

#### File: Logger.h

```
#ifndef INC_LOGGER_H
#define INC_LOGGER_H

#include <deque>

#include "Motor.h"

struct MotorPoint {
        double speed;
        double timeOffset;
};

class Logger{
        private:
                Motor &motor;
                Position &position;
                double startTime;

(31)            deque<MotorPoint> motorPlotData;

                double getTimeDiff();
        public:
                Logger(Motor &m, Position &p);
                //etc...
};
#endif
```

Comment: There is no need to add the tag to your title, please keep it in the tag section. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The namespace of deque is not defined:

```
std::deque<MotorPoint> motorPlotData;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
// ...

deque<MotorPoint> motorPlotData;
```

Comment: std::deque<MotorPoint> is the better idea, as putting a namespace using-directive in a header file increases the potential for name conflicts in the files that include it.

Comment: @ceo:+1, I totally agree with you, but When you are working with mainly one namespace library, it can increase the readability of your code. There is also an alternative: **using std::deque;**

Answer (score 5):

deque is in namespace std, so std::deque.